# In console, ASCII Chars in windows 10 is not correct anymore

Tags: c#, fonts, console, ascii, windows-10

[image]

What I use:

```
Console.WriteLine("╔═╗"); // This
Console.WriteLine("╚═╝"); 
Console.WriteLine((char) 169); // and this
```

I know I can change the font in the console menu:
Properties->Font->

- Font -> Raster Fonts
- Size -> 8x12 (Settings from windows7)

1) But how can we do this in code? (detect Win10 and adapt)

2) It seems that the size of the console is much bigger with these setting compared with windows7? It's anoying because we have like 4 consoles to run together and they don't fit anymore.

3) Other idea: is it eventualy possible to have all the ASCII characters working with the font 'Consolas'?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't customise your command prompt already or install a 3rd party tool? The code you posted works fine for me.

Comment: The characters you are writing are actually *not* ASCII, so they're totally dependent on codepages etc.

Comment: You need to pay attention to Console.OutputEncoding.  If you want to see the box drawing characters with the default raster font (aka Terminal) then you need to select code page 437.  If you changed the font then use utf8.  Changing the defaults is not a great idea, it reproduces poorly on another machine.